# How to click on dynamically changing link in selenium with python

Tags: python, html, selenium

This is the html file:

The problem is that the date on the href is changing every week.

Comment: Show how you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce some waits and use css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.link-lg.pull-right.flip.ng-scope"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```